# Как отправлять ajax запрос с интервалом не смотря на закрытую вкладку в браузере

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Ребят, возможно ли вообще реализовать такое - при клике на кнопку отправлять ajax запрос на сервак с интервалом 1 минута и более для обновления данных в БД не смотря на закрытую  или не активную вкладку в браузере. Решение как бы есть, но работает только если вкладка активна, т.е. в фокусе. Иначе браузер просто останавливает работу setinterval и по сути написанный скрипт просто бесполезен. Буду рад любым советам.

```js
var newDate,
  intervalId,
  intervalId2;

if (localStorage["timer"]) {
  newDate = new Date(localStorage["timer"]);
  timer(); // Инициализация текста в элементах.
  intervalId = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

function onPlows(tm) {
  $('#expand').hide();
  $('.delinfo').hide();
  span.style.display = 'block';
  delplow.style.display = 'none';
  plbtn.style.display = 'none';
  newDate = Date.now() + 60 * tm; // tm - время которое задается в функции при нажатии на кнопку событие onclick
  timer(); // Инициализация текста в элементах.
  if (!intervalId) intervalId = setInterval(timer, 1000);
  intervalId2 = setInterval(updFuel, 60000);
  localStorage["timer"] = new Date(newDate).toISOString();
  localStorage["span"] = true;
}

function timer() {
  intervalId2;
  var now = Date.now(),
    rest = newDate >= now ? Math.round((newDate - now) / 1000) * 1000 : 0,
    s = "";
  if (!rest) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    clearInterval(intervalId2);
    intervalId = null;
    localStorage.removeItem("timer");
    localStorage.removeItem("updFuel");
    localStorage.removeItem("span");
    localStorage.removeItem("selecttract");
    localStorage.removeItem("selectplow");
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '../fieldfunc',
      data: {
        status_pl_field_udt: '2'
      },
      success: function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          window.location.href = "../field";
        }, 2000);
      }
    });
  } else {
    var rest2 = rest % 3600000;
    let hh = (rest - rest2) / 3600000;
    rest = rest2;

    rest2 = rest % 60000;
    let mm = (rest - rest2) / 60000;
    rest = rest2;

    rest2 = rest % 1000;
    let ss = (rest - rest2) / 1000;
    let ms = rest2;

    s = (hh < 10 ? "0" : "") + hh + ":" +
      (mm < 10 ? "0" : "") + mm + ":" +
      (ss < 10 ? "0" : "") + ss;
  }
  document.querySelector("#time").textContent = 'До конца обработки: ' + s;
}

function updFuel() {
  $('.info').remove();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../fieldfunc',
    data: {
      tract_pl_udt: localStorage.getItem("selecttract"),
      fuel_pl_upd: 1
    },
    success: function(result) {
      result = JSON.parse(result);
      $('.updinfo').append('<p class="info" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"> Плуг: ' + localStorage.getItem("selectplow") + '<br>\
    Трактор: ' + result[0].title + '<br>\
    Топлива в баке: ' + result[0].fuel_now + ' литров</p>');
      if (result[0].fuel_now == 0) {
        $errors.text('Закончилось топливо. У Вас есть 3 минуты для заправки топлива.');
        setTimeout(function() {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../fieldfunc',
            data: {
              tract_set: localStorage.getItem("selecttract"),
              fuel_set: 0
            }
          });
          clearInterval(intervalId);
          clearInterval(intervalId2);
          intervalId = null;
          localStorage.removeItem("timer");
          localStorage.removeItem("updFuel");
          localStorage.removeItem("span");
          localStorage.removeItem("selecttract");
          localStorage.removeItem("selectplow");
          window.location.href = "../field";
        }, 1000 * 60 * 3);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn plowsbtn" onclick="onPlows(' + 37000 * $fz + ');">Вспахать</button>
```

UPD "Лучше бы вы описали, что вы хотите сделать(что за скрипт) и какую информацию отправляете в базу?" Ответ: при клике на кнопку запустить таймер обратного отсчета и с интервалом 1 минута обновлять информацию в базе о топливе и обновленную информацию выводить пользователю на экран.

Comment: Нет. Лучше бы вы описали, что вы хотите сделать(что за скрипт) и какую информацию отправляете в базу?

Comment: >Arsen информацию добавил. Но ваш ответ - нет. как то теряет дальнейший смысл развития этой темы

Comment: Мой ответ НЕТ, это к тому, что вы не сможете это сделать таким методом. Можно сделать по другому, при нажатии на кнопку вы сохраняете значение времени (js mktime удобнее) в LocalStorage и делаете свой AJAX запрос каждую минуту. При каждом обновлении контента так же обновляете значение LocalStorage. Если пользователь закроет браузер и откроет страницу через пару часов(как пример), при открытии данной страницы вызываете функцию, которая проверяет Localstorage,  если есть "кука" начинаете новый цикл Ajax запросов.

Comment: Если пользователь закроет браузер и откроет страницу через пару часов.. в этом и заключается вся проблема. Таймер обратного отсчета в таком случае как бы "продолжит" свою работу. К примеру, если установить таймер на несколько часов и пользователь закроет страницу, браузер или вообще пк и вернется через час, то увидит, что время на таймере уменьшилось на час. А вот запросы в это время отправлятся не будут. А это серьезный баг. Потому как все это время не обновляются данные в базе и естественно не уменьшается количество топлива. Вот собственно в чем суть всей проблемы.

Comment: А все потому, что js и php по поводу работы с таймерами, временем и все что с ними связано мягко говоря сделаны через одно место)))

Comment: после всего прочитанного придется забыть об этой затее. реализовать физически не возможно. или я чего то еще не знаю

Comment: а зачем делать это клиентским таймером? Также можно попробовать посмотреть в сторону [Service Worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)

Comment: Он призван быть полностью асинхронным; как следствие, синхронные API, такие как XHR и localStorage, в service worker'е использовать нельзя. а откуда тогда данные о времени брать которые сохраняю в том же LS.. с потолка что ли?

Comment: не вариант. требует настройку браузеров + не очень дружит с андроидом. или я чет не так понял

Comment: и для полного счастья я не нашел даже намека на работу с запросами на сервер. как по мне, то бесполезная штуковина

Comment: Погодите, вы хотите отправлять запросы при **выключенном** компьютере? Это как? Кажется, вы все же не в ту сторону смотрите. Давайте еще раз - зачем вам запускать данный таймер? Он что-то обновляет в БД или только получает данные?

Comment: @ЮраБирюков все эти ваши фолосовские мысли, что "что js и php по поводу работы с таймерами..."  или "после всего прочитанного придется забыть"  свидетельствует, что вы не знаете достаточно данные языки и тем более JS если писали скрип, не понимая, что JS работает на клиентской части и не будет работать с закрытым браузером/вкладкой. Проблема у вас в логике работы "то увидит, что время на таймере уменьшилось на час. А вот запросы в это время отправлятся не будут." а зачем идти запросам, если пользователь не будет видеть? когда откроет страницу, в реальном времени(на данный момент) получит инфу

Comment: >Arsen потому и задал вопрос. я не знаток js. был задуман такой функционал. но, это сделать не получится. по поводу философии) это факт, а не философия. не продумано не в js, не в php никаких возможностей для реализации подобных идей. и да, вы правы, что проблема в логике.. но это, по большому счету, я узнал из ваших ответов.

Comment: Ребят, я новичок и обучаюсь сразу на боевом проекте. за полторы недели основы js, jquery, ajax с ноля. и то что я пишу при таких знаниях не каждый сможет за такой период. и рад вашей критике) это лично для моего дальнейшего развития огромный + .. спасибо)

Comment: >Stepan Kasyanenko да, именно так. ну не возможно, так не возможно) есть одно решение и это естественно не выход, но имеет право на существование. когда вкладка открыта и не находится в фокусе, то вся эта история все таки работает. но и т.с. проблему не решает